# Dell PowerEdge 2950 PCIe Training Error -- No PCIe cards inside

Tags: dell-poweredge, pci-express

So I recently found myself an old PowerEdge 2950, and when I turned it on (after me almost having a heart attack by the sound of it starting up), during post it halted with an error of `PCIe Training Error : Internal PCIe Card`. The weird thing there, is that there aren't any PCIe cards in the 3 slots. [image: empty slots] The rightmost (bottom, in the picture) slot however, seems to come out of the board as an expansion of some sort? Could that be a problem? In case I'm missing something really obvious, I've included a shot of the whole system. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCI *riser* card right in the middle? Yank it out.

If your server boots the it's either a bad PCI riser, or the PCI slot has "gone bad". I know there's a not-noobish explanation for that, but I don't remember it.

If your server *doesn't* boot with the riser out the it's time for a new motherboard/server.

Comment: This is correct. Get the riser out of the equation. In my experience, riser cards don't fail too often. It's probably the motherboard.

Comment: @ewwhite the reason I mentioned the PCI slot "going bad" is it seems to happen on every single R200 I've ever worked with. Even if you take a riser out of a working R200 and put it in it will fail to boot. Anyhow, on a 2950... it's usually a motherboard that's completely toast. :I Hopefully OP will have better luck, though.

Comment: When I took it out, it wouldn't even turn on. The LED panel just read `PCIE Rsr`. After putting it back in, I got the error: `E1410 CPU 1 IERR`. It has two CPUs, should I try taking out 1, and putting 2 where 1 was?

Comment: That worked. And I'm going to accept this answer as correct, because reseating the riser card did help. It just also helped me find the greater problem, a bad CPU.

Comment: And now it's saying the other CPU is bad. I give up for now.